# Battery Icon in Taskbar Missing On Surface Laptop

Tags: drivers, windows-11, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 5 but this should apply to most Surface devices. After messing around with my drivers trying to update a graphics driver, the small battery icon at the bottom right of the screen disappeared. I have tried restarting and there is no option to have a battery icon in settings. I would like help on why the battery icon has dissapeared and how to get it back.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title is at odds with the content, and was edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused be a variety of problems. I will go through my troubleshooting process and share how I fixed the problem.

**Step 1: Check That It Is Not Your Settings**

- Make sure that the battery icon is not just in your icon overflow pane using the arrow in your icons.
- Check that the power icon is selected by right-clicking on the taskbar and selecting taskbar settings.

**Step 2: Check Your Battery Driver**

- Go to settings and try to find out how much charge your battery has by going to settings, system, power and battery. If settings crashes or doesn't load then it is most likely a driver issue
- If it is a driver issue, then open up device manager. Select view make sure show hidden devices is selected. Now select batteries and make sure there are two battery drivers that called 'Micrsoft AC Adapter' and 'Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery'. If there are then right click 'Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery' and press disable. Then right click on it again and enable it. Then restart your computer.

**Step 3: Restart Windows Explorer**

- Go to task manager, identify windows explorer, right click on it are select restart.

**Step 4: Driver Issues**

- You have completed the previous steps and it is still not working, you can try deleting your battery drivers. When you restart your device Windows should identify that they have been uninstalled and reinstall them.
- Check the driver 'Surface Serial Hub Driver' in system devices. If there is an issue with it delete it and restart your device.
- If there is still an issue with the 'Surface Serial Hub Driver' uninstall 'Surface Serial Hub Driver', 'Intel Serial IO UART Host Controller', 'Intel power module plug-in' and then restart your computer. It was this step that solved the problem for me.

Comment: See also https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-restore-missing-battery-icon-windows-10/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Though the link you provided is good and could potentially solve the issue, several of the steps are not applicable or different than Windows 11 and the last section of step 4 in my answer which was the step that fixed the problem was missed out in the webpage you linked to.